# OWIN with VB.NET Legacy Code ASP.NET Web Forms

Tags: vb.net, web-config, owin, c#-to-vb.net, owin-middleware

I am trying to implement OWIN into our legacy vb.net web forms project we have to work with our SSO implementation on Azure. However on start-up I can not seem to be able to run the startup.vb class. I have added:

```
   <add key="owin:AppStartup" value="StartUp" />
   <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="true " />
```

But I still can not seem to launch the StartUp Class I have implemented. What I am expecting is to be redirected to our SSO from Microsoft however that is not happening. There isn't much on the internet for using OWIN with VB.NET also.

```
Imports Owin



Partial Public Class Startup
    Public Sub Configuration(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)
        ConfigureAuth(app)

    End Sub
End Class
```

```
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Extensions
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies
Imports Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect
Imports Owin
Imports System
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Security.Claims
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Partial Public Class Startup
    Private Shared clientId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:ClientId")
    Private Shared aadInstance As String = EnsureTrailingSlash(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:AADInstance"))
    Private Shared tenantId As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:TenantId")
    Private Shared postLogoutRedirectUri As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("ida:PostLogoutRedirectUri")
    Private authority As String = aadInstance & tenantId

    Public Sub ConfigureAuth(ByVal app As IAppBuilder)

        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType)
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions())
        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions With {
            .clientId = clientId,
            .authority = authority,
            .postLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
            .Notifications = New OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications() With {
                .AuthenticationFailed = Function(context) System.Threading.Tasks.Task.FromResult(0),
                .SecurityTokenValidated = Function(context)
                                              Dim claims = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims
                                              Dim groups = From c In claims Where c.Type = "groups" Select c

                                              For Each group In groups
                                                  context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaim(New Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, group.Value))
                                              Next

                                              Return Task.FromResult(0)
                                          End Function
            }
        })
        app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function EnsureTrailingSlash(ByVal value As String) As String
        If value Is Nothing Then
            value = String.Empty
        End If

        If Not value.EndsWith("/", StringComparison.Ordinal) Then
            Return value & "/"
        End If

        Return value
    End Function
End Class
```

Thank You

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you start the app? Is there a particular error message, or status code?

Comment: Go for idenityserver4

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be anything special about using OWIN with VB that wouldn't be adequately covered by C# docs (and appropriate translation to VB).